# Trouble with Bootstrap Layout

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to style two buttons on the same row. On larger devices, I want each button to take up a third of a half of the display. On small devices, I want each button to take up the entire half of the display.

But when I did this, the buttons are not quite even. (One is slightly lower than the first).

[image]

Here is my markup.

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 12px">
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
        <a id="prev-question" href="#" class="btn btn-success col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">Previous</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
        <a id="next-question" href="#" class="btn btn-success col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 disabled">Next</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Could someone help me out a bit here?

**UPDATE:**

To better clarify the layout I'm trying for, the following image shows roughly the layout on a tiny device (top) and a larger device (bottom). (It doesn't need to be this exactly, but because smaller devices have smaller screens, I wanted the buttons to be larger on those devices.)

[image]

Also, I suspect that the issue I'm seeing might be related to the fact that there is no margin between the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the buttons in nested grid columns like this..

```
<div class="row " style="margin-top: 12px">
    <div class="col-xs-6 text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <a id= "prev-question" href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Previous</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-3">
                <a id="next-question" href="#" class="btn btn-success  btn-block">Next</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/kjjp1Ei1GM

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't quite the layout I described I'm looking for. Looking into it further.

Comment: Also, not quite sure why a nested grid. Each grid only contains a single button. Wondering why that needs another nested row.

Comment: Yeah it says "a third of a half of the display" so i was a little confusing. Columns should always be the direct child of `row`, and the nesting makes it work responsively the way you want. How is this not the layout you described?

Comment: I've clarified my description of the layout I want with an image in my question.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize about the centering. Updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

First use `.container` as parent, then use `xs` instead of `sm` because `xs` it is for extra small devices.

```css
.row {
  margin-top: 12px;
  border: red solid
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 text-center">
      <a id="prev-question" href="#" class="btn btn-success col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">Previous</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 text-center">
      <a id="next-question" href="#" class="btn btn-success col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">Next</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a `<div class="container">` higher in the DOM hierarchy. And I am already using `xs` for extra small devices. But I wasn't in the outer `<div>`. I can see the buttons are level for you. I'm looking into this further, but it isn't they layout I described that I'm after.

Comment: then next time put your full relevant code. and please  tell which layout are you looking for in small devices?

Comment: From my question: *"I'm trying to style two buttons on the same row. On larger devices, I want each button to take up a third of a half of the display. On small devices, I want each button to take up the entire half of the display."* On very small devices, I want each button to take up about a half, as it shows in my screenshot.

Comment: That's closer for tiny devices, but not for larger ones. If you're curious, I've clarified the layout I was trying for in my question.